# Invalid geo coordinates for Foursquare API

Tags: api, foursquare

I was doing a project exploring Los Angeles data with Foursquare API. However, I got an error 'groups'and  'meta' the error details showed 'invalid geo coordinates'.

1. My accounts have enough calls
2. Lat and Lng values in my dataframe are all in the correct order, no reverse

How can i proceed from the error? Is there a way to ignore this error and move on?
Please see below for my code (the formulas all comes from my lab class. The only change is'Los Angeles' coordinates input, and sadly it no longer works)

```
address = 'Los Angeles, CA'

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="la_explorer")
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
latitude = location.latitude
longitude = location.longitude
print('The geograpical coordinate of Los Angeles are {}, {}.'.format(latitude, longitude))
```

after the run i got:The geograpical coordinate of Los Angeles are 34.0536909, -118.2427666.

```
def getNearbyVenues(names, latitudes, longitudes, radius=600, LIMIT=100):

    venues_list=[]
    for name, lat, lng in zip(names, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)

        # create the API request URL
        url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?&client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}&ll={},{}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(
            CLIENT_ID, 
            CLIENT_SECRET, 
            VERSION, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            radius, 
            LIMIT)

        # make the GET request
        results = requests.get(url).json()["response"]['groups'][0]['items']


        # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
        venues_list.append([(
            name, 
            lat, 
            lng, 
            v['venue']['name'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lat'], 
            v['venue']['location']['lng'],  
            v['venue']['categories'][0]['name']) for v in results])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for venue_list in venues_list for item in venue_list])
    nearby_venues.columns = ['Neighborhood', 
                  'Neighborhood Latitude', 
                  'Neighborhood Longitude', 
                  'Venue', 
                  'Venue Latitude', 
                  'Venue Longitude', 
                  'Venue Category']

    return(nearby_venues)

print(results)
```

after the run i got:

{'meta': {'code': 400, 'errorType': 'param_error', 'errorDetail': 'Invalid geo coordinates (-118.169810,34.497355)', 'requestId': '5ec0766ac8cff2001ce42bf2'}, 'response': {}}

Please help! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

(-118.169810,34.497355) is invalid geo coordinates. latitude and longitude are in reverse order. Try 
(34.497355,-118.169810)

Answer (score 0):

Actual coordinates of Your address is `34.0536909, -118.2427666` it seems latitude and longitude are swapped change it